# JavaScript match passwords

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit new to JavaScript. I'm trying to write a function for my website to check if the password entered by the user matches a predetermined password ("abc"). The password is entered in a form.

Here's what i got so far, although it does not seem to be working.

```
function done() { 
var the_pass="abc";
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

if(password.value.match(the_pass))   
{   
alert('Correct, try another...')  
return true;  
}  
else  
{   
alert('Wrong...!')  
return false;  
}
```

Comment: don't forget to check the console for errors

Answer (score 2):

your missing the closing bracket of the done() function - try to indent your code so that you can easily match the braces at the startand end of functions, and use the comparison operator to check the value against the password. Best not to store actual passwords this way though - not very secure and anyone looking at the source code can easily see the password.

```
function done() 
 { 
    var the_pass="abc";
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

    if(password == the_pass) 
    {   
       alert('Correct, try another...');
       return true;  
     }  
   else  
    {   
       alert('Wrong...!');  
       return false;  
     } 
 }
```

Comment: its only for an assignment.. not actually going to be used.
this code is still not working... there's no output..

Comment: the function is fine - but what about the rest of it ? edit your question and post the rest of the html / javascript code you have

Answer (score 1):

```
if(password == the_pass)   
{   
alert('Correct, try another...')  
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

use string comparision. ( '===' is compare include type checking)

```
if(the_pass === password) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
```

and
for pattern matching test, you can use regexp.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match